# Searching for a better way to set default values in my config class?

Tags: php

I reuse a Config class (simplified code at the bottom) in a lot of my projects. It's generally instantiated once in my app bootstrap file and stored in a container class from which I inject it as a dependency into objects via static "makeThis()" method calls.

Because it's instantiated every time my apps are executed I want to streamline it as much as possible. Repeat: **I'm looking to make this process as efficient as possible.**

I have default config values specified in the `Config::$defaults` array at instantiation. What I want to optimize specifically is the assignment of properties inside the `load_conf_environment()` function. You'll find code comments inside this function further elucidating my requirements.

The code below should be clear enough (to anyone capable of providing a valid answer) to illustrate how the class works. I'm looking for an imaginative and efficient way to handle this operation and I'm not averse to a massive refactoring if you can support your claim.

Finally, let me pre-emptively rule out one suggestion: *NO, I'm not interested in using constants for the directory path* values. I used to do that but it makes unit testing difficult.

---

**UPDATE:**

- I've considered using [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) to determine the default
  value's type and subsequently cast the passed value, but according to
  the php docs this is not a good solution.
- Currently I'm storing the different config directive names in arrays
  by type and doing a check to see which array contains the directive
  name and perform a typecast or assign values based on that. This seems "ugly" to me
  and is what I'm trying to get away from if possible.

---

**UPDATE2:**

Having config values match the variable type of the defaults is the ideal situation, but I kind of just got it into my head that I wanted it that way ... it may not even really matter. Maybe it should just be incumbent upon the coder to provide valid configuration values? Anyone have any thoughts on that?

---

```
<?php

class Config
{  
  /**
   * The base application directory in which all app_dirs reside
   */
  protected $app_path;

  /**
   * Configuration directives
   * 
   * @var array
   * @access protected
   */
  protected $vals = array();

  /**
   * List of default config directive values
   * 
   * @var array
   * @access protected
   */
  protected $defaults;

  /**
   * Class constructor -- basically sets default values
   * 
   * @param string $app_path Base application directory
   * 
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct($app_path=NULL)
  {    
    $this->defaults = array(
      'debug'               => FALSE,
      'autoload'            => FALSE,
      'is_cli_app'          => FALSE,
      'is_web_app'          => FALSE,
      'smarty'              => FALSE,
      'phpar'               => FALSE,
      'front_url'           => '',
      'app_dir_bin'         => 'bin',
      'app_dir_conf'        => 'conf',
      'app_dir_docs'        => 'docs',
      'app_dir_controllers' => 'controllers',
      'app_dir_lib'         => 'lib',
      'app_dir_models'      => 'models',
      'app_dir_test'        => 'test',
      'app_dir_vendors'     => 'vendors',
      'app_dir_views'       => 'views',
      'app_dir_webroot'     => 'webroot',
    );

    if ($app_dir) {
      $this->set_app_path($app_path);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Setter function for $app_path property
   * 
   * @param string $app_path Path to the app on the server
   * 
   * @return void
   * @throws ConfigException On unreadable/nonexistent path
   */
  public function set_app_path($app_path)
  {
    $app_path = dirname(realpath((string)$app_path));
    if (is_readable($app_path)) {
      $this->app_path = $app_path;
    } else {
      $msg = 'Specified app path directory could not be read';
      throw new ConfigException($msg);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Set default values for uninitialized directives
   * 
   * Called after $cfg file is read and applied to fill
   * out any unspecified directives.
   * 
   * @return void
   */
  protected function set_defaults()
  {    
    foreach ($this->defaults as $key => $val) {
      if ( ! isset($this->vals[$key])) {
        $this->vals[$key] = $this->is_app_dir($key)
        ? $this->app_dir . '/' . $this->defaults[$key]
        : $this->defaults[$key];
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * (Re-)Loads configuration directives
   * 
   * @param mixed $cfg Config array or directory path to config.php
   * 
   * @throws ConfigException On invalid config array
   * @return void
   */
  public function load_conf_environment($cfg)
  {
    // Reset all configuration directives
    $this->vals = array();

    if ( ! is_array($cfg)) {
      $cfg = $this->get_cfg_arr_from_file($cfg);
    }

    if (empty($cfg)) {
      $msg = 'A valid $cfg array or environment path is required for ' .
        'environment configuration';
      throw new ConfigException($msg);
    }

    foreach ($cfg as $name => $val) {

      // does a setter method exist for this directive?
      $method = "set_$name";
      if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        $this->$method($val);
        continue;
      }

      /*
        ASSIGN SPECIFIED DIRECTIVE VALUE
        THE ASSIGNED VALUE SHOULD BE OF THE SAME TYPE SPECIFIED by $this->defaults

        IF DIRECTIVE IS ONE OF THE 'app_dir' VARS:
          - IF IT'S A VALID ABSOLUTE PATH, SET THAT AS THE VALUE
          - OTHERWISE, app_dir PATHS SHOULD BE RELATIVE TO $this->app_path

        I CONSIDERED USING gettype() TO DETERMINE THE DEFAULT VAR TYPE
        AND THEN CAST THE VALUE, BUT THE DOCS SAY THIS IS A BAD IDEA.
      */

    }

    // set default vals for any directives that weren't specified
    $this->set_defaults();

    if ( ! $this->vals['is_cli_app'] && ! $this->vals['is_web_app']) {
      $msg = 'App must be specified as either WEB or CLI';
      throw new Rasmus\ConfigException($msg);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Load a configuration array from a specified file
   * 
   * If no valid configuration file can be found,
   * an empty array is returned. Valid config paths
   * 
   * @param string $path Config environment directory path
   * 
   * @return array List of config key=>value pairs
   * @throws ConfigException On invalid environment path
   */
  protected function get_cfg_arr_from_file($path)
  {
    $path = (string)$path;
    $path = rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . '/config.php';

    if (is_readable($path)) {
      require $path;
      if (is_array($cfg) && ! empty($cfg)) {
        return $cfg;
      }
    }
    return array();
  }

  /**
   * Has the specified config directive been loaded?
   *
   * @param string $directive Configuration directive name
   * 
   * @return bool On whether or not a specific directive exists
   */
  public function is_loaded($directive)
  {
    return isset($this->vals[$directive]);
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves a key=>value list of config directives
   * 
   * @return array List of configuration directives
   */
  public function get_directives()
  {
    return $this->vals;
  }

  /**
   * Magic method mapping object properties to $vals array
   * 
   * @param string $name Object property name
   * 
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function __get($name)
  {    
    if (isset($this->vals[$name])) {
      return $this->vals[$name];
    } else {
      $msg = "Invalid property: $name is not a valid configuration directive";
      throw new OutOfBoundsException($msg);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Handling default values** 
Is there a reason why you set defaults for directives that need them **after** loading values from the config file?

Since the defaults are already hard-coded in the `__construct`, why not just move them to the `$vals` property and avoid needing to set them later on? This way, your `load_conf_environment` method overwrites the default value that already exists for the directive.

**Validating types** 
This is something I would enforce with each directive's setter method. Each setter should verify the type of value with the `is_*` functions or by type-hinting in the setter arguments and throw exceptions accordingly. I would probably go so far as to require each directive have a setter. It's more work, but cleaner and 100% enforceable.

**Handling app_dir directives** (one option)

1. In the construct, if `set_app_path` is called, run through the vals property and call the `set_app_dir_directive` method (see below) on the app_dir directives so that they are prefixed with the app path.
2. Make a new `set_app_dir_directive` method:

   ```
   public function set_app_dir_directive($key, $val)
   {
       $this->vals[$key] = $this->app_dir . '/' . $val;
   }

   // then...

   public function load_conf_environment($cfg)
   {
       ...

       foreach ($cfg as $name => $val) {

           $method = "set_$name";
           if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
               ...
           }

           if ($this->is_app_dir_directive($name)) {
               $this->set_app_dir_directive($name, $val);
               continue;
           }

           // Continue storing vals.
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: +1 for being smarter than me. Now that you mention it, I can't think of a good reason why. The main problem I have is how to filter new values so that they adhere to the same type as the default.

Comment: Hehe this is kind of how I got to this point -- I was trying to eliminate as many setter methods as possible to shorten the code. I think everything would be solved if I had a bunch of setter methods in there, but I was hoping to find a way to do it without them. This may not be possible, though, if I want to handle a bunch of variables of different type. At one point I implemented __set() to catch the different assignments without setters, but the problem is that I don't want __set() to be available to assign values outside of the load_conf_environment() method either.

Comment: I'm going to go with this. Thanks for digging into the code -- I know it involves work to understand what someone else is thinking.